# Shower Handle Replacement: Pull-out to Lever-out

Tags: plumbing, shower, trim

My (approx 25 year old) shower currently has a common handle style on it (the clear/crystal type); I pull the handle out to start water flow and twist to adjust water temp.  It is essentially this style, with (I believe) a Moen 1225 cartridge:

[https://www.amazon.com/LASCO-Simpatico-31661P-Chateau-Escutcheon-Polished/dp/B0083GDBP4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0083GDBP4)

I'd like to replace it with a type of handle that levers out and the lever handle then rotates to adjust the temp.  Is this possible?  I ask because I see lever-style replacements available, but those pull out and then twist in essentially the same way/function as the current handle, and I'd like something that lifts/levers to start the water flow instead.

Comment: Moen does have lever style handles available (these days they ship those and will send they style you have if you request one) but the motion won't change without replacing the whole valve.

Comment: I have a rotary handle and it shuts off when fully ccw. Putting a lever on this type of faucet may end up damaging it as pulling on the lever and pushing  will put quite a bit of torque on the faucet body. The best way would be to put in the proper type if you want to change or you may find water in places you don’t want while repairing this one.

Comment: @Ecnerwal, I would have marked this as a co-answer if I could have :--)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to operate your existing cartridge in a lifting up or down, back and forth motion to start or stop the flow of water. Your cartridge's motion is strictly in and out on a straight plane. It will rotate clockwise and counter clockwise to adjust the temperature. If you did find a handle that fit, you'd have to pull the handle straight out to start the flow and push it straight in to stop the flow. You'd need a cartridge that has a stem that moves back and forth and also turns clockwise and counterclockwise. They don't make one that will fit in your faucet. You'll have to replace your faucet if this will keep you up at night thinking about it.